# Triangle That Prints With Numbers as rows

Tags: java, for-loop

I Have an assignment asking us to create a triangle that looks like this with only for loops and I'm currently unable to change my asterisk into those numbers I can turn the whole triangle into a number.

[image]

Here is my code to print out a triangle:

```
 public class ExtraCredit_Bazar {

    public static void main ( String arg[] ){

       for (int i=1; i<10; i += 2)
       {
            for (int k=0; k < (4 - i / 2); k++)
            {
                 System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");

       }
  }
```

Comment: Are you asking a question, or trying to hire a programmer?

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using this site here i will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you do not know how to get proper numbers for every level. You can do it like this:

```
public class ExtraCredit_Bazar {

    public static void main ( String arg[] ){

       for (int i=1; i<10; i += 2){
            for (int k=0; k < (4 - i / 2); k++){
                 System.out.print(" ");
            }
            int number = 1;
            for (int j=0; j < (i/2); j++){
                System.out.print(number);
                number *= 2;
            }
            for (int j= (i/2); j < i; j++){
                System.out.print(number);
                number /= 2;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, I've split your for-loop printing '*' into two for-loops. The first one prints a number and multiplies it by two for the next iteration. Then, when the middle is reached, the second loop comes in and it divides number by two to get it smaller again.

Comment: So I used your code into the program and it prints the triangle but it print 1 on the top then 0 as the rest

Comment: And do you assign number = 1 before every run of the for loops?

Comment: Yes it is underneath the main method

Comment: Just compiled it, works completely fine. I edited my post so that you can see the whole code. I've just done what I've written to do: inserted my two for-loops instead of the one using variable "j" from your code.

Comment: I found the error it was when I put your code into my program I had mistakenly typed the wrong thing thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Edit your second inner loop like this:

```
int number = 1;

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    System.out.print(number);

    if (j < i / 2) {
        number *= 2;
    } else {
        number /= 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number in the middle should be easy to get. For the rest of the numbers i recommend saving the Strings to a array before printing them to center the strings based on the length of the longest (last) String.

```
public class ExtraCredit_Bazar {

    public static void main ( String arg[] ) {
       int z = 1;
       final int lineCount = 8;
       String[] lines = new String[lineCount];
       // do first iteration "by hand" 
       String left="1";
       String right="1";
       lines[0] = left;

       for (int i=1; i<lineCount ; i++)
       {
            // update z here

            // update left here

            lines[i] = /*concat strings here (left, right and maybe spaces)*/;

            // update right here Integer.toString(int) if necessary
       }

       final int maxStringLength = lines[lineCount-1].length();
       for (int i = lineCount-2; i >= 0; i--) {
           // add spaces to the left of lines[i] dependent on it's
           // length and maxStringLength

           // if you do it right, you can reuse the spaces you add to the
           // left and don't have to create them from the start.
           // Therefore the "backwards iteration". 
       }

       // print the lines
}
```

You may have noticed that there is code missing. You should be able to figure that out on your own easyly, if you know the basics of java (and math).